# Convert special characters to string

Tags: android, string, sockets, inputstream

I am stuck on this weird problem. What I am doing is communicating 2 devices via bluetooth. When I send special characters like ß à æ é , I receive  question marks like this ????? on the other device. Here is the code on the receiving side

```
private class ConnectedThread extends Thread {

        private final Socket mmSocket;
        private final InputStream mmInStream;
        private final OutputStream mmOutStream;

        public ConnectedThread(Socket socket) {
            Log.d("ConnectionService", "create ConnectedThread");
            mmSocket = socket;
            InputStream tmpIn = null;
            OutputStream tmpOut = null;

            // Get the BluetoothSocket input and output streams
            try {
                tmpIn = socket.getInputStream();
                tmpOut = socket.getOutputStream();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.d("ConnectionService", "temp sockets not created", e);
            }

            mmInStream = tmpIn;
            mmOutStream = tmpOut;
        }

        public void run() {
            Log.i("ConnectionService", "BEGIN mConnectedThread");

            byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
            int bytes;

            // Keep listening to the InputStream while connected
            while (true) {
                try {
                    // Read from the InputStream
                    bytes = mmInStream.read(buffer);

                    if(bytes==0){
                        break;
                    }
                    String message = new String(buffer, 0, bytes);
                    Log.d("PC-DATA", message);
                    inputAnalyzer(message);

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.d("ConnectionService", "disconnected", e);
                    connectionLost();
                    break;
                }
            }

            connectionLost();
        }

        public void write(byte[] buffer) {
            try {
                mmOutStream.write(buffer);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.d("ConnectionService", "Exception during write", e);
            }
        }

        public void cancel() {
            try {

                mmSocket.close();
                connection = false;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.d("ConnectionService", "close() of connect socket failed",
                        e);
            }
        }
    }
```

after reading from the input stream i convert buffer into String in this way.

```
String message = new String(buffer, 0, bytes);
```

Is this wrong or something else I am missing !
Any help ?

Comment: Where are you seeing question marks?  In the actual data, or when printing the data to log/screen?  Your font may just not have those characters defined in the second case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
String message = new String(buffer, 0, bytes);
```

Never convert bytes to a character representation without mentioning the correct character set. Use this instead.

```
String(byte[] bytes, int offset, int length, String charsetName)
```

UTF-8 should be able to display most special characters. If it does not suit your case, use a charset that covers the characters you expect the clients to receive.

Comment: thank you for your answer , I tried all these but didnt work in my case. US-ASCII 
ISO-8859-1   
UTF-8
UTF-16BE
UTF-16LE
UTF-16

Comment: Thanks now its working. I was making mistake from server side. I was encoding it in ASCII. Now I am using UTF-8 on both sides and now its working great.